# How to count the number of same elements which are in order in a vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, sum

I have for example a vector like this one:

`x<-c(1,1,1, -1, 1,1,1,1,1,1, -1,-1,  1,1, -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, 1)`

and I want the algorithm to product a vector (3,1,6,2,2,7,1)

which means 3 of "1s", 1 of "-1s", 6 of "1s" etc...

I have developed the following algorithm but it doesn't work for every vector x, which probably I am going to have.

```
y<-c(0)
q=0
z=0
w=0
e=1

if (x[1]==1)
{
q<-abs(sum(x[1:(min(which(x < 0))-1)]))
y[e]<-q
k=q+1
z<-abs(sum(x[k:min(which(x < 0))]))
e=e+1
y[e]<-z
k=k+z
r<-matrix(c(which(x < 0)))
w<-matrix(c(which(x > 0)))

while( k<22 )

{

if( all(r<k) )
{
z<-sum(x[k:22])
e=e+1
y[e]<-z
k=k+z
}else
{
z<-abs(sum(x[k:min(r[which(r > k)]-1)]))
e=e+1
y[e]<-z
k=k+z
}

if( all(w<k) )
{
z<-abs(sum(x[k:22]))
e=e+1
y[e]<-z
k=k+z
}else
{z<-abs(sum(x[k:min(w[which(w > k)]-1)]))
e=e+1
y[e]<-z
k=k+z
}

}}
```

But for the vector 
`x<-c(1,1,1, -1, 1,1,1,1,1,1, -1,-1,  1,1, -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)`
it works.

Do you have any idea to do this faster and easier or just to find the problem in my own code??

Thank you all!

Comment: Hi, you can  try the function table

Comment: @MamounBenghezal `table(x)` will give total `1`s and `-1`s, but not how many there is of each in each sequence

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can try function `rle`:

```
rle(x)
#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:7] 3 1 6 2 2 7 1
#  values : num [1:7] 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1
```

and so `rle(x)$lengths` gives you what you want:

```
rle(x)$lengths
#[1] 3 1 6 2 2 7 1
```

***Efficiency comparison between @clemlaflemme functions and `rle`:***

```
library(microbenchmark)

x <- rep(x,5000)

microbenchmark(clem_shift(),cath_rle(),clem_cumul(),unit="relative")
#Unit: relative
#         expr        min        lq        mean     median         uq        max neval cld
# clem_shift()   1.000000   1.00000   1.0000000   1.000000   1.000000  1.0000000   100  a 
#   cath_rle()   1.181513   1.13419   0.8552573   1.095478   1.041918  0.9483564   100  a      
# clem_cumul() 325.480391 284.14827 170.1371421 265.160409 241.954976 54.5240969   100   b
```

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis, you're welcome, rle is a very useful function ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Just for information, you could have written this small piece of code to sort out this by yourself

```
cumul = c()
cur = 1
for(i in 2:length(x)){
   if(x[i] == x[i-1]) cur = cur + 1
   else{
       cumul = c(cumul, cur)
       cur = 1
   }
}
cumul = c(cumul, cur)
```

But of course, using `rle` function is simpler. After @CathG comments, an other hand written function you could have think of if using only 0 and 1:

```
clem = function(X){
    shift = c(0,seq(X)[as.logical(c(X[-1] - head(X,-1), 1))])
    shift = shift[-1] - head(shift,-1)
    return(shift)
}
```

And then the benchmark against `rle`:

```
X = runif(1000)<0.5
> microbenchmark(cath(),clem(),unit = "relative")
Unit: relative
   expr      min      lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
 cath() 1.115647 1.10824 1.220533 1.102692 1.098195 9.22847   100
 clem() 1.000000 1.00000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.00000   100
```

Comment: for sure it's optimized ; that was just because I was quite affraid by the amount of code written for such a simple thing and so to illustrate a naive easy way for doing it. I've added a hand written optimized function. Not an expert with `microbenchmarking`but it sounds better than `rle`in my computer

Comment: (+1) for your second solution, which is clever and indeed a bit more efficient (although not "significantly": both methods get "a" for `microbenchmark`, see my edit) than `rle` (probably because `rle` also computes the value in each sequence). You could replace the second line by `diff(shift)` though or even get the solution directly by `diff(c(0,seq(x)[as.logical(c(x[-1] - head(x,-1), 1))]))` ;-)

Comment: that's also what SO is for and where I learnt `rle` function ;-D